# How long to get this website public?

Tags: discussion, beta

Upto how many days will the website remain in beta until it gets public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Private Beta** phase is about a week long.

The **total beta** period is *at least* 90 days long, but it takes [as long it takes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).

One can see our site's progress on our [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design).

Comment: +1 :) and Im the 8th top user.. yay!

Comment: Congrats! :) Where do we see the top users on GD SE? Update: Never mind. :) It's on the Area 51 page.

Comment: @JFW also: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users